# apply a function to list in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach

I'm trying to learn  Scala.
I ask for help to understand loop **foreach**
I have a function, it reads only last csv from path. But it works when I point only one way:

```
val path = "src/main/resources/historical_novel/"
def getLastFile(path: String, spark: SparkSession): String = {

  val hdfs = ...}
```

but how can I apply this function to the list such as

```
val paths: List[String] = List(
  "src/main/resources/historical_novel/",
  "src/main/resources/detective/",
  "src/main/resources/adventure/",
  "src/main/resources/horror/")
```

I want to get such result:

```
src/main/resources/historical_novel/20221027.csv
src/main/resources/detective/20221026.csv
src/main/resources/adventure/20221026.csv
src/main/resources/horror/20221027.csv
```

I create df with column (path), then apply function through WithColumn and it is work,
but I want to do it with **foreach**, understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` applies a function you define or provide on each element in a `Collection`.

The simplest example is to print each path to the console

`paths.foreach(path => println(path))`

To apply a series of functions as you describe you can use `{}` in the `foreach` body and call multiple functions.

```
paths.foreach(path => {
    val file = loadFile(path)
    writeToDataBase(file)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say your function is like this

```scala
def f(s: String): Unit = {}
```

you can simply do this

```
paths.foreach(p => f(p))
```

After your edit, I think you may want use `map`, a function that can transform a collection to another collection. like this

```scala
val result = paths.map(p => getLastFile(p, yourSparkSession))
```

Comment: sorry, would you explain what does mean "p"?

Comment: Or, thanks to automatic η-conversion, just `paths.foreach(f)`.

Comment: the `p` is the symbol of every element the produced by your list `paths`. you can choose whatever name you like.  in `foreach` we treat every element the same way.